# Android Espresso test error: No static method loadSingleServiceOrNull()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

When I ran my tests 1 week ago every was fine, but now I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method loadSingleServiceOrNull(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Landroidx/test/internal/platform/ServiceLoaderWrapper; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.test.internal.platform.ServiceLoaderWrapper' appears in /data/app/com.domain.myapp-1/base.apk)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerModule.provideUiController(UiControllerModule.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerModule_ProvideUiControllerFactory.provideUiController(UiControllerModule_ProvideUiControllerFactory.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerModule_ProvideUiControllerFactory.get(UiControllerModule_ProvideUiControllerFactory.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerModule_ProvideUiControllerFactory.get(UiControllerModule_ProvideUiControllerFactory.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:6)
at androidx.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent$ViewInteractionComponentImpl.viewInteraction(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView(Espresso.java:1)
```

This line throws error:

```
onView(withId(R.id.sign_in_button)).perform(click())
```

What could be the cause? Thank you.

Comment: what is this method `loadSingleServiceOrNull` did you created this method in your app?

Comment: I didn't create any of these methods

Comment: are you sure this is not part of any of your code because when I google search this string there is nothing apart from this question as result.

Comment: I'm sure. Doesn't it say it's in class: `in class Landroidx/test/internal/platform/ServiceLoaderWrapper`?

Comment: `appears in /data/app/com.domain.myapp-1/base.apk`**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Issue occurred to me when I updated

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

to

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

Reverting to version 3.3.0 fixed things.

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it. Wondering what the underlying cause is.

Comment: I also had to downgrade to `3.3.0`. Worth mentioning is, that this exception started to occurre only for espresso tests for fragments with navigation and viewmodels scoped to it.

Comment: This is not real solution. Please refer to answer provided by @vahidlazio for correct one.

Answer (score 19):

You have multiple `ServiceLoaderWrapper`, the one that actually has the API method is some of them, This file is brought by `androidx.test:monitor`, I fixed it by forcing the version of the package in the app gradle file as following.

```
android {
  ...
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.test:monitor:1.4.0'
     }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

upgrading to 3.5.1 and removing the espresso-contrib dependency solved it for me